# Can I use Firebase Cloud Functions & Firestore as a cache server?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make an Android app.
It uses some rest api. (The Rest API is not mine, external 3rd party server)
But the provider restricts the api, 20 request per 1 second.
In my case, it is too short.
So I want to cache the data in my backend.
And I want to make my backend using Firebase.

1. Firebase cloud function should be run always and it request the rest api instead of user (20 request per 1 second)
2. It stores the response in the Firestore or Realtime database (Firebase).

Step 2 has no problem.
But I don't know whether step1 is possible or not.
Generally, cloud function is used as a trigger.
But in my case I want to use it like a crawler(?).
It should always run without any trigger.
I knew it is not free, It is for paid service.
Is it possible?
Are there anything what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can access/trigger your cloud function via a http GET.

Your function that, can query the database and make a lookup, if it needs
to refresh it's data in the database.

If so, it queries your restricted rest api, stores the result into your database and returns then the output as the result of your GET request.

Comment: Sorry, in my case, I use another external rest api server. It's not mine. I should get the data from the external server and store it in the firebase db.

Comment: That's what I said. client -> GET to your function -> function checks your db -> if needed queries rest API -> stores into db -> return result to client

Comment: Cool... It's easy... THX :)